# Drag and drop with webdriver (webdriverio) works unexplainably

Tags: testing, automated-tests, webdriver, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I need to create automated tests on a drag-and-drop functionality. Long story short, I created a highly simplified example, where I can't understand why does it (either Webdriver itself or webdriverio npm module) behaves that way.

The html markup is incredibly simple:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>foo</title>
  <style>
    #foo {
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: grey;
      margin: 300px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo" draggable="true">
    AAA
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The test method I call to drag the div is (I also tried to use the `browser.action() … .perform()` chain of methods) of webdriverio, but the behavior seems to be the same, so I don't think this is a bug in the `.action()` method:

```
async dummyTest() {
  const e = await this.browser.$('#foo');
  const eSize = await e.getSize();
  await this.browser.performActions([
    {
      type: 'pointer',
      id: 'mouse-one',
      actions: [
        {
          type: 'pointerMove',
          origin: e,
          duration: 100,
          x: 0,
          y: 0,
        },
        {
          type: 'pointerDown',
          button: 0,
        },
        {
          type: 'pointerMove',
          origin: e,
          duration: 100,
          x: Math.round(eSize.width / 2),
          y: 0,
          //y: 100,
          //y: -100,
        },
        {
          type: 'pause',
          duration: 8000,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
}
```

The screenshots taken by Webdriver don't show the element being dragged, so I had to take pictures with the phone.

This is when I drag `y: -100,`:

[image]

This is when it's dragged with `y: 0,`:
[image]

And this is with `y: 100,`:
[image]

**Apparently, the origin of the drag is much upper, then the element with the AAA text, which is dragged.**

Could anyone help me to understand what's going on? Is it a bug in Webdriver or do I simply misunderstand the API?

---

I'm using webdriverio v8.1.3, but the behavior was present in version 7* also.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, 10/1/23 the most appropriate answer to this question is that it simply doesn't work with Webdriver itself.

- The being dragged element's 'transparent image' doesn't appear where it would normally apper, if a human user performed the drag action. It appears much higher on the page, as if the OS/window manager spaces is not counted when using x and y in Webdriver.
- also the 'dragover' event (may be other related events as well) are not fired correctly at all.

So for now the only feasible solution I see is to skip the drag-and-drop functionality tests or do them manually.